# "Of the day" vs "of a day"

Tags: idioms, articles

Could you tell me what is right:

> 1. Dinner is the most substantial meal of the day

Or

> 2. Dinner is the most substantial meal of a day

I think the first one is correct, but we don't talk about particular day that's why I doubt. Because we talk about all days and that's why we shoul use 'a day'
Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a native speaker:

Use "**of the day**" to mean "comparing all meals in one average day." As with all idiomatic expressions, a complete explanation is not always available to explain why one preposition fits and others do not.  Rather, you need to know only "what is the common expression?" The answer is not always the most substantial **of the year**.